# Show data in Nested Recyclerview in android

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, retrofit

As I fetched and show the dates (see image) as the title of the main recyclerview. I want to show the available slots data instead of the 0 1 2 etc elements. The code is attached below

**Url for json data**

> https://run.mocky.io/v3/c9bd7858-0e41-422f-b1d2-cd490c08583b

[image]

**AppointmentTimeActivity.java**

```
public class AppointmentTimeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;

Button appointmentTimeButton;
private TextView doctorFullName;
ConstraintLayout constraintLayout;


public static List<List<String>> availableSlots;

RecyclerView rvGroup;
public static ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup;
LinearLayoutManager layoutManagerGroup;
GroupAdapter groupAdapter;

private DoctorScheduleResponse timings;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.select_appointment_time);

    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Appointment time");
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(this);

    constraintLayout = findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    appointmentTimeButton = findViewById(R.id.book_video_call_appointment_btn);

    doctorFullName = findViewById(R.id.doctor_full_name);
    rvGroup = findViewById(R.id.rv_group);

    String docName = getIntent().getStringExtra("doctorFullName");

    doctorFullName.setText(docName);

    arrayListGroup = new ArrayList<>();

    fetchAndShowAppointmentsTime();

}

private void fetchAndShowAppointmentsTime() {
    String id = String.valueOf(SpecialityActivity.doctorID);

    Call<DoctorScheduleResponse> call = RetrofitClient.getInstance().getMyInterface().getAppointmentTime("Bearer " + sharedPrefManager.getAccessToken(), id);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<DoctorScheduleResponse>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(@NotNull Call<DoctorScheduleResponse> call, @NotNull Response<DoctorScheduleResponse> response) {
            arrayListGroup = new ArrayList<>();

            if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                assert response.body() != null;
                for (List<Slot> slots : response.body().getSlot()) {
                    for (Slot slot : slots) {
                        arrayListGroup.add(slot.getScheduleDate());
                    }
                }
                
                groupAdapter = new GroupAdapter(AppointmentTimeActivity.this, response.body().getSlot());
                layoutManagerGroup = new LinearLayoutManager(getApplicationContext());
                rvGroup.setLayoutManager(layoutManagerGroup);
                rvGroup.setAdapter(groupAdapter);

            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(@NotNull Call<DoctorScheduleResponse> call, @NotNull Throwable t) {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

---

**DoctorScheduleResponse.java**

```
public class DoctorScheduleResponse {

@SerializedName("slot")
@Expose
private List<List<Slot>> slot = null;

public List<List<Slot>> getSlot() {
    return slot;
}

public void setSlot(List<List<Slot>> slot) {
    this.slot = slot;
}
```

}

---

**GroupAdater.java**

```
public class GroupAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<GroupAdapter.ViewHolder> {

private Activity activity;
ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup, arrayListMember;
LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager;
SharedPrefManager sharedPrefManager;
List<List<Slot>> slotsList;

public GroupAdapter(Activity activity, ArrayList<String> arrayListGroup) {
    this.activity = activity;
    this.arrayListGroup = arrayListGroup;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
            .inflate(R.layout.custom_slot_layout, parent, false);
    return new ViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {


    holder.dummyTV.setText(arrayListGroup.get(position));
    arrayListMember = new ArrayList<>();
    sharedPrefManager = new SharedPrefManager(activity);

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        arrayListMember.add(String.valueOf(i));
    }

    CustomAdapter customAdapter = new CustomAdapter(arrayListMember);
    LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(activity);
    holder.rvMember.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
    holder.rvMember.setAdapter(customAdapter);

}


@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return arrayListGroup.size();
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView dummyTV;
    RecyclerView rvMember;


    public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        dummyTV = itemView.findViewById(R.id.dummyTextView);
        rvMember = itemView.findViewById(R.id.rv_member);

    }
}
```

}

---

**CustomAdapter.java**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.SlotsViewHolder> {

ArrayList<String> slots;


public CustomAdapter(ArrayList<String> slots) {
    this.slots = slots;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public SlotsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.available_slots_list, parent, false);
    return new CustomAdapter.SlotsViewHolder(view);
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull SlotsViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.tvSlots.setText(slots.get(position));
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return slots.size();
}

public class SlotsViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    TextView tvSlots;

    public SlotsViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        tvSlots = itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv_slots);

    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Nested recycler view will be more complex in terms of memory. So you can achieve same UI with different approach.

You should try with single recycler view with dynamic layout binding.
Example: For single item of recycler view, there will be a header(for date) and a viewgroup(may be linear layout) then bind any no. of child views inside that linear layout.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in GroupAdater.java. Inside onBindViewHolder method you are adding the value of loop variable to your list that you pass to your nested recycler view adaptor.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    arrayListMember.add(String.valueOf(i));
}
```

You have to add the correct date from arrayListGroup object.